# Programming to find if a number is prime

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, for-loop, primes

I'm writing a piece of code using JavaScript to check if a number is prime or not. The code correctly tells me the result for number = 1,2,3 but fails on certain others such as 10. I can't figure out what the problem is that is causing it to fail on only certain numbers. If anyone can help identify the problem and suggest a fix I would be grateful.

```
if (total < 2) {var prime = "this is not a prime number"}
if (total == 2) {prime = "this is a prime number"}
if (total == 3) {prime = "this is a prime number"}
for (var l = 2; l <= Math.sqrt(total); l++) {
  if (total % l == 0) {prime = "this is not a prime number"}
  else {prime = "this is a prime number"}
}
```

the code is used in a html file as part of a function

Comment: You need to break out of the loop as soon as you discover the number isn't prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should exit out of the loop as soon as you know that it's not a prime, otherwise the result will be overwritten in the next itaration. There is actually no point in having the `else` clause (as it just sets the same value over and over), just set that value before the loop:

```
prime = "this is a prime number";
for (var l = 2; l <= Math.sqrt(total); l++) {
  if (total % l == 0) {
    prime = "this is not a prime number";
    break;
  }
}
```

Side note: You don't need to check the values `2` and `3` separately before the loop, those will be catched by the first two iterations in the loop.

Comment: That algorithm is right but not appropriate for performance. You should ignore even numbers except of 2. You should increase loop by 2 on every step. That increases the performance

Answer (score 0):

First, for prime numbers you don't need to check even number (2,4,6 etc), so your for loop could go from 3 and l=l+2.

Secondly, how does you function fail? seems like you should remember the state, and if it is not prime break the loop(or if it is, don't know what do you want).

Also, you could optimize this more by doing for loop to half of the wanted number. So if you want to go from 3 to sqrt(total), you can optimize by going to sqrt(total)/2.

Answer (score 0):

Guffa your approach is right but you can increase the efficiency of your algorithm for large numbers by including two conditions.
1. Check whether a number is divisible by 2. 
     For even numbers, it directly gives the result. 
     This condition already lessens the number of repetitions by half if the 
     number is odd.
2. There is a very interesting fact about Prime numbers, which most people 
   don't know. Every Prime number only comes either exactly before a multiple of 6 
   or exactly after that multiple of six.What I mean by that. e.g.,54 is a 
   multiple of 6. There must be a prime number either before or after 56.Let's
   check : 54+1 = 55 , not a prime number : 54-1 = 53 a prime number.SO, the claim 
   is clear. Now we will use this property in reverse 'Every Prime number must 
   have a multiple of 6 before or after it.' If I have to check whether 105 is a 
   prime number or not.
   a. Check whether 105+1 = 106 is a multiple of six? No 
   b. Check whether 105-1 = 104 is a multiple of six? No
   So 105 can never be a prime number.
3. You may notice that there is an ambiguity in this algorithm. You can only 
   decide whether a number is not prime with this property but it does not tell 
   you the certainty of the number to be prime. I mentioned that you have to check 
   for a multiple of 6 and if it is then there should be a prime number before or 
   after that multiple but it is not clear whether it is before or after that. So, 
   you have to deal with that too. We can only check for not Prime but it can 
   reduce a lot of computation.

My Code:-

```js
// The following code is written in Python. But anyone beginner level Programmer can understand it.

i = '140740731462387462836487236478236487236487384783'
k = int(i)
if (int(i[-1])%2 == 0): #Get the last didgit of the number and check if it is 
                        #even.One can also just divide the whole num by 2
    print('a.Not a Prime')
elif not((k-1)%6==0 or (k+1)%6==0):#Check for multiple of six.
    print('b.Not a Prime')
else :
    for j in range(3,int(k**(1/2))+2,2): # Final approach.Increment index by 2 
                                         #because you have already checked for 
                                         #even numbers.
        print(j)
        if (k%j==0):
            print('c.Not a Prime'+str(j))
            check=0
            break
        check =1
if (check ==1):
    print('A prime Number')
```

Thanks,
Mahyar Ali

Answer (score 0):

This solution checks whether number is prime in O(root of n) time:

```
function isPrime(num) {
    if (num <= 4) {
        return num > 1 && num < 4
    }
    i = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num))
    while (i >= 2) {
        if (num % i === 0) return false
        i -= 1
    }
    return true;
};

console.log(isPrime(47)) //true
```